# ReactJS - fly to cart animation

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I found [this example](https://demo.discussdesk.com/flying-products-to-shopping-cart/index.html) about a fly to cart animation but it's in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( 0 < $('.product button').length ) {
        $('.product button').click(function() {
            var offset = $(this).parent().offset();
            $(this).parent().clone().addClass('product-clone').css({
                'left' : offset.left + 'px',
                'top' : parseInt(offset.top-$(window).scrollTop()) + 'px',
                'width' : $(this).parent().width() + 'px',
                'height' : $(this).parent().height() + 'px'
            }).appendTo($('.product').parent());

            var cart = $('nav .navbar-right strong').offset();
            $('.product-clone').animate( { top: parseInt(cart.top-$(window).scrollTop()) + 'px', left: cart.left + 'px', 'height': '0px', 'width': '0px' }, 800, function(){
                $(this).remove();
                var price = parseInt($('nav .navbar-right').attr('data-price'));
                var productPrice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-price'));
                var cartPrice = parseInt(price+productPrice);
                $('nav .navbar-right strong').html('$' + cartPrice);
                $('nav .navbar-right').attr('data-price', cartPrice);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I've read it's not advisable to use jQuery with React but I have no idea how to convert that  jQuery code since I'm new to React.

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import { LazyLoadImage, LazyLoadComponent } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import 'react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css';
import AddToCartBtn from "../components/addToCartBtn";
import FavoriteBtn from "../components/favoriteBtn";
import config from "../utils/config";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import styles from "../public/assets/css/productSliderCard.module.css"

function ProductSliderCard({id, title, slug, price, stock, image, productInfoHandler, redirectToLogin}) {
    const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);
    
    const addToCartAnimation = () => {
        
    }

    return (
        <LazyLoadComponent>           
            <div
                className={styles.sliderItem}
                onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovering(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovering(false)}
            >
                {
                    stock === '0' &&
                    <span className={styles.outOfStock}>
                        RUPTURE DE STOCK!
                    </span>
                }
                <div className={styles.imageContainer}>                   
                    <LazyLoadImage
                        {/* the part of the component I want to animate */}                        
                        width="100%"
                        alt={image}
                        effect="blur"
                        src={config.BASE_URL + 'images/products/' + image}
                    />                  
                    {
                        isHovering &&
                        <div className={styles.productHoverDetails}>
                            <div className={styles.productDetails}>
                                <label className={styles.productTitle}>{title.toUpperCase()}</label>
                                <br/>
                                <label className={styles.price}>CHF {price}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                                <div className={styles.row}>
                                    <div className={styles.col}>
                                        <FavoriteBtn
                                            productId={id}
                                            redirectToLogin={redirectToLogin}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={styles.col}>
                                        {
                                            stock !== '0' &&
                                            <AddToCartBtn
                                                addToCartAnimation={addToCartAnimation}
                                                productId={id}
                                                redirectToLogin={redirectToLogin}
                                            />
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={styles.col}>
                                        <span
                                            className={styles.infoBtn}
                                            onClick={() => productInfoHandler(slug)}
                                        ></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </LazyLoadComponent>
    )
}

export default ProductSliderCard;
```

So with the `addToCartAnimation` function, I want to clone `LazyLoadImage` and animate it to my shopping cart just like in the example I linked above.

Comment: Hello have you found any solution?

Comment: @DilshodSh hello, unfortunately no

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fly-to-cart-raw-react-forked-5r30de?file=/src/components/Item.js:0-2924 I found this

Comment: but could not figured out how it works

Comment: when you find any solution please tell me okay?

Comment: I also found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccfbIdv5_Y8

Comment: @DilshodSh check out my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with!

With each add to cart click, I update a context (which is an array of objects) with the coordinates of the image.

```
const containerRef = useRef();

const addToCartAnimation = () => {
    const data = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    // key for map function generated here  
    data['key'] = Math.random();
    data['image'] = image;

    // updating context
    updateAnimationDOMRects(data);
}

return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
        <img/>
    </div>
)
```

Documentation on `getBoundingClientRect` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Then I have a component to handle the animation

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import config from "../utils/config";
import testSpecialChars from "../utils/testSpecialChars";
import {CartAnimationContext} from "../context/cartAnimationContext";

const CartAnimationImg = ({image, top, left, width, height}) => {
    const { cartDOMRects } = useContext(CartAnimationContext);
    // calculating how many pixels the image need to
    // translate from it's location to the cart location
    const animation = `
        @keyframes fly {
            0% { transform: translate(0) scale(1); }
            100% { transform: translate(${(cartDOMRects.left + (cartDOMRects.width / 2)) - left - (width / 2)}px, ${(cartDOMRects.top + (cartDOMRects.height / 2)) - top - (height / 2)}px) scale(0); }
        }
    `;

    return (
        <div>
            <style children={animation} />
            <div
                style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    zIndex: 10,
                    top: top + window.scrollY + "px",
                    left: left + window.scrollX + "px",
                    width: width + "px",
                    height: height + "px",
                    animationDuration: "1s",
                    animationIterationCount: 1,
                    animationName: "fly",
                    animationTimingFunction: "ease",
                    animationFillMode: "forwards"
                }}
            >
                <img
                    src={`${config.BASE_URL + (testSpecialChars(image) ? 'api/image/' : 'images/')}products/${image}`}
                    style={{
                        width: "100%"
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartAnimationImg;
```

This is the way I am rendering the animation component:

```
{
    animationDOMRects.map((item) => (
        <CartAnimationImg
            key={item.key}
            image={item.image}
            top={item.top}
            left={item.left}
            width={item.width}
            height={item.height}
        />
    ))
}
```

If you have no other choice than using a random key for the map function (like in my case), make sure the keys are generated **outside** the map function, otherwise all previous animations will be triggered again at the same time.